# Python SSL Certificate Error using request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting the following error while using `request` package in Python.

```
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
```

I'm trying to access a link using the following code:

```
content = requests.get(link, verify=True, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"})
```

I searched for some solutions and found a few that talked about `Install Certificate.command`, but I can't find the file in my Python directory. I'm using Python 3.8. Any suggestion on how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to provide the certificate to prevent this error from occuring.

```
cert = requests.certs.where()
        page = requests.get(link, 
                            verify=cert, 
                            headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"})
```

This worked for me